# Summoning Buster Blader from graveyard

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Are there any ways to summon [Buster Blader, the Dragon Destroyer Swordsman](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Buster_Blader,_the_Dragon_Destroyer_Swordsman) from the graveyard?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any ways to summon Buster Blader, the Dragon Destroyer Swordsman from the graveyard?

No, there are not.

The card text explicitly forbids it, by stating it can *only* be Fusion Summoned. From the card text, emphasis mine:

> **Must be Fusion Summoned and cannot be Special Summoned by other ways.** This card cannot attack directly. This card gains 1000 ATK and DEF for each Dragon-Type monster your opponent controls or is in their Graveyard. Change all Dragon-Type monsters your opponent controls to Defense Position, also Dragon-Type monsters in your opponent's possession cannot activate their effects. If this card attacks a Defense Position monster, inflict piercing battle damage to your opponent.

Comment: Would dimension gate work on him

Comment: Nope. The card can *only* be summoned by Fusion summon and by no other means, as stated in its text